# What are the ethical and legal issues of self driving cars being released in the UK?

Tags: autonomous-vehicles, ethics

What are the ethical and legal issues of self driving cars being released in the UK?

This question came up on our exam today and I was left in a daze.

I initially thought it would be issues like the legal driving age for self driving cars since they are AI do you need a minimum age limit?

Another one I thought was whether or not you need driving licenses for AI cars?

Could someone please list all the possible ethical **and** legal issues that surround AI controlled cars?

Comment: This question might be deemed too broad in that you're asking for a list of *all* possible ethical and legal issues.  This is also region specific, and the ethical issues for the UK may be different from the US because US and UK laws differ...  I'm going to attempt a general answer by linking you to articles you can peruse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## LEGAL

**Legislative:**

http://cyberlaw.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Automated_Driving:_Legislative_and_Regulatory_Action

http://www.ncsl.org/research/transportation/autonomous-vehicles-self-driving-vehicles-enacted-legislation.aspx

http://spectrum.ieee.org/transportation/advanced-cars/selfdriving-cars-will-be-ready-before-our-laws-are

**Liability**:

https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/cars/2017/04/03/tesla-mishap-raises-issues-self-driving-liability/99880620/

https://www.nytimes.com/2014/05/14/upshot/when-driverless-cars-break-the-law.html?_r=0

**Regulation:**

https://www.theverge.com/2016/9/19/12981448/self-driving-car-guidelines-obama-foxx-dot-nhtsa

**Law Review**

https://www.americanbar.org/publications/youraba/2015/october-2015/are-we-there-yet--the-legal-aspects-of-driverless-cars.html

## ETHICAL

https://www.technologyreview.com/s/542626/why-self-driving-cars-must-be-programmed-to-kill/

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/driverless-cars-will-face-moral-dilemmas/

http://news.stanford.edu/2017/05/22/stanford-scholars-researchers-discuss-key-ethical-questions-self-driving-cars-present/

---

This should be enough to get you started.  (In terms of how it may apply in the UK, I leave that for you to determine;)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, it's best if you could summarize or cite each of them, in case the links are dead.